# Charging a device with a power bank

Tags: voltage, current, charging, wireless-charging

So my device has an input of 5V 0.7A, but the cable isn't detachable from the plug so I need to use a different USB to micro-USB cable.

My power bank can output on 2 ports, DC 5V 1A and 5V 2.4A

If I plugged in the device to the 1A port, it should only draw 0.7A and not 1A right? And would the same go for the 2.4A port?

The device is a wireless charger, if that's relevant. I just want to make sure I don't fry my device or watch.

Comment: 1) the **voltages** need to be **the same**, in your case they're all 5 V so that's OK. 2) the current needed by the power consuming device (in your case the wireless charger) needs to be **less** than what the power delivering device can deliver. Your consumer consumes up to 0.7 A, your power delivering device can deliver 1 A or more. So that's OK as well. The actual current that flows is set by the power consuming device (the wireless charger) so it's 0.7 A (or less if it needs less). The power bank does not determine the current.

Comment: Got it! If you want to post that as an answer, I'll mark as answered.